# Special characters issue with Laravel Query in Controller (tried many possibilites of solving)

Tags: database, laravel

I have been trying to retrieve data from my database. It was working fine until I started to query words with special characters (I speak Portuguese so we use a lot of accents). In my controller I have:

```
public function showall() {

     $horarios = Horario::All();
     $professores = array();

     foreach($horarios as $horario) {
         $professor_primeiro_nome[$horario - > id] = DB::table('professors') - > where('id', '=', $horario - > professor_id) - > pluck('primeiro_nome');

         $professor_primeiro_nome[$horario - > id] =
             trim($professor_primeiro_nome[$horario - > id], '[""]');

         $professor_ultimo_nome[$horario - > id] = DB::table('professors') - > where('id', '=', $horario - > professor_id) - > pluck('ultimo_nome');

         $professor_ultimo_nome[$horario - > id] =
             trim($professor_ultimo_nome[$horario - > id], '[""]');

         $materias[$horario - > id] = (string) DB::table('materias') - > where('id', '=', $horario - > materia_id) - > pluck('materia');

         $materias[$horario - > id] = trim($materias[$horario - > id], '[""]');

     }

     return View::make('veraulas',
         compact('horarios', 'professor_primeiro_nome',
             'professor_ultimo_nome', 'materias'));
 }
```

In the view I have:

```
<!-- Table Headings -->
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Professor</th>
        <th>Matéria</th>
        <th>Data</th>
        <th>Início</th>
        <th>Fim</th>
        <th>Ver Detalhes da Aula</th>
        <th>Editar Aula</th>
        <th>Remover Aula</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<!-- Table Body -->
<tbody>
    @foreach ($horarios as $horario)
    <tr>
        <!-- Task Name -->
        <td>
            <div>{{ $professor_primeiro_nome[$horario->id] }} {{ $professor_ultimo_nome[$horario->id] }}</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>{{ $materias[$horario->id]) }}</div>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form>
                {{ csrf_field() }}

                <button>Ver Detalhes</button>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form>
                {{ csrf_field() }}

                <button>Editar</button>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form>
                {{ csrf_field() }} {{ method_field('DELETE') }}

                <button>Remover</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

The page looks like this:

[image]

The words have strange characters...I can I do to solve this?

Comment: Others words look fine. The problem appears when I query the database and pass the result to an array.

Comment: Are these symbols being stored correctly in the DB itself? Correct collation?

Comment: Yes. Interesting thing is that all other data retrieved from database are correct. When I use pluck and pass the data to array, the words become like that.

Comment: Only `pluck` method? If you retrieve with `get`, data is correct?

Comment: I tested now. With get passing to array still returns strange data:

Comment: I don't know what else to do. I only get C\u00e1tia instead of Cátia. There is no reason for this.

Comment: I solved! I think passing to array was changing the coding. I made a Raw select and it worked. $horarios = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT p.primeiro_nome, p.ultimo_nome, m.materia, h.data, h.inicio, h.fim
       FROM horarios h, professors p, materias m
       WHERE h.professor_id = p.id
       AND h.materia_id = m.id
       "));

Comment: That is good, however it is still interesting to find reason of the problem with initial code (I believe it has to be solvable).

Comment: I think that too. Thank you for your questions. They made me think differently about the problem.